# Python KeyError: 'C'

Tags: python, keyerror

I am trying to code for a tables of logarithms. The output is supposed to be three lines for the total number of cities, unique population counts, and first digits frequency distributions, and then three columns for the digit, count, and percentage.

This is my current code:

```
    
def main():       
    
    population=set()
    #declaring dictionary to hold the count of #each digit
    digits={}
    #initializing totCities to 0 that holds the count of total number of cities
    totCities=0
    #initializing all digits in the dictionary to 0
    for i in range(1, 10):
        num=str(i)
        num=num[0]
        digits[num]=0
#opening Census_2009.txt file
    try:
        infile=open("Census_2009.txt",'r')
#throwing error if file cannot be opened and exiting the program
    except OSError:
        print("Could not open file")
        exit()
#ignoring the headernext(infile)
  #iterating through each line in file
    for i in infile:
#incrementing totCities for each city
        totCities+=1
        line=i.rstrip().split('\t')
#adding each population count to the set and incrementing the count of the first digit in #the dictionary
        population.add(line[-1])
        digits[line[-1][0]]+=1
#closing Census_2009.txt
    fileinfile.close()
#opening benford.txt file to write the Output
    outfile=open("benford.txt",'w')
    print("Output written to benford.txt")
#writing the output to the file
    outfile.write("Total number of cities: {}\n".format(totCities))
    outfile.write("Unique population counts: {}\n".format(len(population)))
    outfile.write("Digit\tCount\tPercentage\n")
    for key, value in digits.items():
        outfile.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(key, value, round(((value/totCities)*100), 1)))
#closing benford.txt
    fileoutfile.close()
    
    
main()
```

However, I get this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-15-061b69b87f23>", line 28, in main
    digits[line[-1][0]]+=1

KeyError: 'C'
```

Any idea on what this error is for specifically of how to fix it?
Sorry for the lengthy code.

Comment: Need a sample of the file so it's reproducible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: `line` is a list of strings. So `line[-1]` is a string and `line[-1][0]` is just a single character, namely 'C'.  And since digits only contains `1-9` it will give a `KeyError` when asked for `digits['C']`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out the `print(line[-1][0])` is probably giving something you didn't expect, i.e. `'C'` instead of a digit. We can't see your input data do it's hard to know whether it's an issue with the data being inconsistent, or if you're picking the wrong field.

If you are convinced your code is picking the correct field, but it's an occasional line of data you are content to ignore, you can do a quick partial bulletproofing of that section with something like

```
pop_field = line[-1]
if pop_field.is_numeric():
    population.add(pop_field)    
lead_char = pop_field[0]
if lead_char.isnumeric():
    digits[lead_char]+=1
```

Some other unsolicited tips, take them or leave them:

- You can probably just use the integers 1-9 as the dictionary keys rather than converting to strings.
- You can use a shortcut to initialize the dictionary, such as

`digits = dict((d, 0) for d in range(1, 10))`

`# digits will be {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}`

- For counting tasks, the `collections` module has a `Counter` class that handles most use cases.

Good luck!